# What does a structure like "il ne parle que..." means ?

Tags: sens

I was reviewing my notes from my French class and I can not find the meaning of this sentence anywhere. What does it mean exactly?

Comment: Can you give us more context?

Comment: @Fractaliste The exact example of my notes was "Il ne parle que français", and that it is already answered and explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the phrase is used in a sentence such as:

> Il ne parle que [le français]

It means he can only speak (and understand) [French].

If it is used in a sentence like:

> Il ne parle que de [cette journée]

It means he talks only about that [day].

Answer (score 1):

It means the same as:

> He only understands/speaks...

or

> The only thing he understands/speaks is ...